# Referencing parameters inside TransformedTargetRegressor

Tags: scikit-learn

Sklearn 20-dev has a new feature - sklearn.compose.TransformedTargetRegressor. Consider using it together with sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.

```
pipelines = {
    'P0_baseline': {
        'tuned_parameters': {
            'feature_encoder__handle_unknown': ['ignore'],
            'DecisionTreeRegr__max_depth': [5, 15, 45, 135],
            'DecisionTreeRegr__random_state': [42],
            'preprocessing__validate': [False]
        },
        'pipeline': sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline([
            ('preprocessing', FunctionTransformer(my_preprocessing_function)),
            ('feature_encoder', sklearn.preprocessing.CategoricalEncoder()),
            ('DecisionTreeRegr', TransformedTargetRegressor(
                regressor=sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor(),
                func=np.log,
                inverse_func=np.exp
            ))
        ])
    },
}
```

The problem is that 'DecisionTreeRegr__max_depth' and 'DecisionTreeRegr__random_state' are not are passed to TransformedTargetRegressor, not to DecisionTreeRegressor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass the params to an internal object, you need to reference that as `'mainobject__internalobject__param'`.

Try

`'DecisionTreeRegr__regressor__max_depth'` in place of `'DecisionTreeRegr__max_depth'`.

Same for other parameters that you want to pass down to the tree.
See the documentation of [set_params()](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.TransformedTargetRegressor.html#sklearn.compose.TransformedTargetRegressor.set_params).